# What is the best practice to deploy an angular application with Spring boot using Spring Webflux?

Tags: angular, spring-boot

I'm developing a web application using angular and Spring boot based on Spring Webflux with default Reactor Netty.
What is the best practice for production deployment using those stacks?

I would have liked to deploy my angular application inside Spring Boot and build a jar file containing both angular and spring boot source code as
described in the link: https://dev.to/jakmar17/deploying-angular-application-inside-spring-boot-57g7

But It seems that It is not possible with Netty

What would be the best practice?
Is it creating a shell script as follows :

```
java -jar mySpringBootApp.jar # launch Spring boot application 
http-server [path] [options] # launch the angular application with npm: http-server package
```

Or is there another way to do so?

Comment: And why wouldn't that be possible? It is just static content.